# Установка базы данных при инсталляции приложения

Tags: android, java, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как можно сделать, чтобы заполненная разработчиком бд могла использоваться на всех мобильных устройствах автоматически?

Т. ею чтобы я ее заполнил, собрал приложение и при установке бд устанавливалась вместе с приложением и использовалась без проблем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Я делал на пэка саму базу данных, а при первом старте приложения выкладывал её из ассэтов в папку с базами.
   Только тут есть ограничение на размер одного файла в ассете - это 1 мегабайт.(По крайней мере когда я делал так было). Поэтому приходилось разделять на несколько файлов и при копировании во внутреннюю память соединять.
2. Еще, как вариант, можно сформировать описание данных в XML или JSON и при первом запуске запускать специальную Activity(с прогресс баром и сообщениями), которая будет читать из вашего описания данные и класть их в базу так, как вы опишете. Это даже более гибкое решение чем моё.
3. Можно хранить всю нужную информацию на сервере и ваше приложение при каждом запуске будет определять не изменилась ли она и есть ли информация внутри самого приложения. И при необходимости все обновлять с сервера.

Конкретнее о структуре базы sqlite в андройд можно найти в интернете. Например [вот](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/) ссылка.

Comment: ограничение на размер можно обойти просто изменив расширение файла с БД с .sqlite (или .db) на пример, на .mp3 (то есть на расширение несжимаемого ресурса)

Answer (score 1):

Существует отличная библиотечка [Sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).
Сначала создаете базу на пк (если по винду, то например с помощью [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)),
кладете в assets/databases,
наследуетесь от SQLiteAssetHelper и хелпер автоматически установит базу для приложения.

Если же база содержит очень много данных, возможно стоит закачивать их сети, выборочно необходимые пользователю.